# How to check neighbor character is specific character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check whether left-neighbor and right-neighbor of marked (selected) text is `*` ?

Actually I'm trying to create a `B`-icon like stackoverflow textarea. In other word, there is a element like this:

```
<span id='bold'>bold</span>
```

Also there is a textarea like this:

```
<textarea id="txtarea" rows="4" cols="50"> this is a test. </textarea>
```

Now assume I have selected `is` in that textarea, if l-r-neighbor is `**` then remove them and if there is anything else than put `**` then put `**` around `is`. How can I do that?

**Note:** I can get selected-text using this code: `$("#txtarea option:selected").text();`

Comment: You'll probably want to take a look at the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties.

Comment: @showdev I don't want to replace `**` with `<b>`, I need to check wheter neighbor character is `**` or not ...

Comment: why not use an existing markdown editor?

Comment: @charlietfl Is there any example? If do you mean is something like [this](http://summernote.org/), I have to say I want to have my own textarea

Comment: sure... do a google search will find numerous examples using different scripts

Comment: @charlietfl Ah I see what's your point ..! And actually I'm using a [markdown](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/) to generate proper output ... But now, I want to create some shortcut-buttons like (`B`, `I`, `U` and ...) to implements some rules on selected-text ... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Find one that has the features you need and is well documented. The last part is the most important.